# Configuring Jersey-Maven project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to write a sample REST web services demo using Jersey.
After creating a Maven project - this is the error I have

> Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type Cannot read lifecycle mapping
>   metadata for artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:maven-plugin:2.5:runtime
>   Cause: error in opening zip file  pom.xml /MyRestDemo line 1  Maven
>   Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

Screen shot

[image]

Per suggestions on previous stack overflow posts,

1. I have deleted the .m2 repository and updated the project - error persists.
2. I have deleted just maven - clean plugin still have the same error.

I have the same error with both Eclipse Neon and Luna and I am stuck at this point.

Thanks

Comment: can you explain in detail please

Comment: What you say makes no sense, i recently 3 months back tried Jersey demo on eclipse and it worked fine, can you please specify error and highlight it.

Answer (score 0):

Set of Actions that could be taken according to eclipse foundation: https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html

Modify you POM.xml with below plugin.

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

> The above should work fine, if still you are facing problem then Go to
>   **.m2/repository** , delete all files. come to eclipse and rebuild your project.

One more reason for the above error could be a bad download of artifact, please check the proxy details of your company or home in (**~/.m2/settings.xml**)

Comment: I have updated the plugin as you have mentioned, still have the same error.
Edited my original post with the image

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely weird error message:

```
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:maven-plugin:2.5:runtime 
Cause: error in opening zip file pom.xml
```

"ZIP file `pom.xml`"? Why would it think that? Maybe try to run Maven from the command line (or using Run -> "Maven ..." inside of Eclipse). That might give you a different / better error message.

If that doesn't help, some background: m2e (the Maven plugin for Eclipse) tries to figure out which Maven targets it should run as part of the build inside of Eclipse. `mvn clean` is one of them. To see what m2e thinks, select the project, right click, Properties, Maven, "Lifecycle Mapping".

The target `clean:clean` should be mapped to "ignore" since Eclipse already does that well.

Which makes me wonder why it wants to run in your case.

If the mapping is correct for you, then sometimes m2e get stuck in weird ways. Try to update the project (right click project, Maven, "Update Project..."). Make sure "Update project configuration from pom.xml" is enabled.

If that also doesn't work, then something broke your Eclipse installation. Try to install the latest version of Eclipse and try to open the project there.

Comment: Hi, I have checked Project-> properties-> Maven - Lifecycle Mapping and all it says is cannot read pom.xml

Comment: @appu This is *very* weird. Is there a file `pom.xml` in the root folder or your project? Is that a text file? Can you open it in a text editor?

Comment: @appu Post a screenshot of your project directory layout (just the root folder is enough, don't open the `src/` or other folders inside of the project).